# Tiled Instance Normalization

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, batch-normalization, style-transfer

I am currently implementing a few image style transfer algorithms for Tensorflow, but I would like to do it in tiles, so I don't have to run the entire image through the network. Everything works fine, however each image is normalized differently, according to its own statistics, which results in tiles with slightly different characteristics.

I am certain that the only issue is instance normalization, since if I feed the true values (obtained from the entire image) to each tile calculation the result is perfect, however I still have to run the entire image through the network to calculate these values. I also tried calculating these values using a downsampled version of the image, but resolution suffers a lot.

So my question is: is it possible to estimate mean and variance values for instance normalization without feeding the entire image through the network?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a random sample of the pixels of the image, and use the [sample mean](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleMean.html) and [sample variance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SampleVariance.html) to normalize the whole image. It will [not be perfect](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProbableError.html), but the larger the sample, the better. A few hundred pixels will probably suffice, maybe even less, but you need to experiment.

Use [`tf.random_uniform()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_uniform) to get random X and Y coordinates, and then use [`tf.gather_nd()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) to get the pixel values at the given coordinates.

Comment: I tried downsampling the image, skipping rows/columns and random sampling, however the issue is that once the sampled image goes through the convolutional network there are a lot of nonlinearities that compromise the mean/variance calculations of intermediate layers. If I do a downsampling the image loses resolution, as if it was processed in a smaller size, and if I do random sampling the result is over-saturated.

Comment: I mean use the mean and variance from the random sample to normalize the _whole original full-resolution image_, or the _full resolution tiles_.

Comment: Yes, but that only takes care of the input normalization, it doesn't take into account the normalization of internal layers. Random sampling will produce very different convolutional results, since it takes into account neighbor information, so I don't think this method would work.

Comment: One alternative that gives fairly good results is first running the network on all tiles, calculating the instance normalization values for each layer, and then averaging them. These values are then used to run the network a second time, again for each tile but now without calculating normalization parameters and using the precalculated ones.  However, this requires data to be processed twice.

Comment: Yes, that's also workable. You asked "is it possible to estimate mean and variance values for instance normalization without feeding the entire image through the network" so that's what I was trying to answer.